# Altering passed parameters in Java (call by ref,value)

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I actually thought that I had a good idea of how passing values in Java actually work, since that was part of the SCJP cert which I have passed. That was until today, when I at work discovered a method like this:

```
public void toCommand(Stringbuffer buf) {

  buf.append("blablabla");
}
```

Then the caller of that method used the function like this:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
toCommand(buf);
String str = buf.toString();
```

Now I thought that that code would give str the value "", but it actually give it the value from the mehod. How is this possible? I thought things didnt work like that in Java?

Either way... it should be considered a bad practice to write code like this in Java, right? Because I can imagine it can bring some confusion with it.

I actually spent some time searching on this, but my interpretation of what these sources are saying, is that it shouldnt work. What am I missing?

```
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html
http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm
```

Sebastian

Comment: You should ask for your money back on the SCJP - I'm sure they should have taught you this! :-)

Comment: @mikera +1 It's one of the central points of the language, passing objects as a parameter, I'm quite astonished they've missed it.

Comment: @Taisin: I agree. I have never paid much attention to certifications, but this is just plain *sad*.

Comment: Im pretty sure they tend to use the classes String (immutable) and Object for their questions. Object doesnt have any methods that can change anything about the object, so that is probably why I have missed out on this detail. Im pretty sure I have never failed these type of questions when preparing for the SCJP nor on the actual test. 

Anyways, instead of sending the StringBuffer as parameter I would have preffered to create the buffer within the method and return buffer.toString. But maybe thats not optimal in all cases, like when assembling an email, as someone proposed.

Comment: @sebastianlarsson Actually, the very fact that you had to ask such a question after certification tells a lot of the certification value. The thing is, it's not a detail, it's a crucial point of the language. It's astonishing they missed it in the questions. Btw, sending the StringBuffer as parameter is a quite good practice when text operations are split in several methods - if you, f.ex, assembling a status report through many objects, inheritence, etc. Economizes memory. String operations are heavy.

Comment: I just looked it up in the book I had for the certificate. It actually mentions that "The original object can be changed in the called method by using the passed reference to the
object."
For the test I just studied the things that I was unsure of and I had heard that "Java is call by value - always" several times, so I guess I might have actually been wrong if there were any questions on that. =)

You really shouldnt need a SCJP to know that, so no disrespect to the certificate itself. I felt it was an enlightening test.

Answer (score 11):

Java is pass-by-value. The *value* of an object reference is an object *reference*, not the object itself. And so the `toCommand` method receives a copy of the value, which is a reference to the object — the same object that the caller is referencing.

This is exactly the same as when you're referencing an object from two variables:

```
StringBuffer buf1;
StringBuffer buf2;

buf1 = new StringBuffer();
buf2 = buf1; // Still ONE object; there are two references to it
buf1.append("Hi there");   
System.out.println(buf2.toString()); // "Hi there"
```

Gratuitous ASCII art:

```
                  +--------------------+
    buf1--------->|                    |
                  | === The Object === |
                  |                    |
    buf2--------->|    Data:           |
                  |      * foo = "bar" |
                  |      * x = 27      |   
                  |                    |
                  +--------------------+
```

Another way to think of it is that the JVM has a master list of all objects, indexed by an ID. We create an object (`buf1 = new StringBuffer();`) and the JVM assigns the object the ID 42 and stores that ID in `buf1` for us. Whenever we use `buf1`, the JVM gets the value 42 from it and looks up the object in its master list, and uses the object. When we do `buf2 = buf1;`, the variable `buf2` gets a *copy* of the value 42, and so when we use `buf2`, the JVM sees object reference #42 and uses that same object. This is not a literal explanation (though from a stratospheric viewpoint, and if you read "JVM" as "JVM and memory manager and OS", it's not a million miles off), but helpful for thinking about what object references actually are.

With that background, you can see how `toCommand` gets a *reference* (42 or whatever), not the actual `StringBuffer` object data. And so operations on it look it up in the master list and alter its state (since it holds state information and allows us to change it). The caller sees the changes to the object's state because the *object* holds the state, the reference just points to the object.

> Either way... it should be considered a bad practice to write code like this in Java, right?

Not at all, it's normal practice. It would be very hard to use Java (or most other OOP languages) without doing this. Objects are big compared to primitives like `int` and `long`, and so they're expensive to move around; object references are the size of primitives, so they're easily passed around. Also, having copies of things makes it difficult for various parts of a system to interact. Having references to shared objects makes it quite easy.

Comment: The author of one of the articles I posted says that since it is references that are copied and not actually objects, performance isnt an issue.

Comment: @sebastianlarsson: It's true that the smaller the amount of data you're moving around, the faster things will tend to be. I wouldn't call it a *central* point, but it's true nevertheless.

Comment: Great example. I have edited the code so that it sets `buf2 = buf1` *before* it appends to `buf1`. I hope that is OK and that it makes it even more explicit exactly what's going on. i.e. `buf2` is not a copy of the `buf1` object.

Comment: @mikej: Thanks for doing that. I wasn't sure about it at first, but the more I thought about it, the smarter it was. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuffer` is **mutable**. The `toCommand()` method gets a **reference** to that objects which is **passed by value** (the reference), the reference allows the method to change the mutable `StringBuffer`.

If you are thinking about why we cannot do this with `String` it is because `String` is **immutable** in which case it will result in the **creation of another `String` object** and not having the changes reflected in the object of which the reference is passed.

And I don't see why it should be bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the in the method, when you pass an object, a **copy** of a **reference** to the object is passed by value. Consider the example below:

```
    public class Test {

     public static void modifyBuff(StringBuffer b)   {
        b.append("foo");
     }

     public static void tryToNullifyBuff(StringBuffer b)   {
        b = null; // this will not affect the original reference since 
                  // the once passed (by value) is a copy
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();  // buff is a reference 
                                                 // to StringBuffer object

        modifyBuff(buff);

        System.out.println(buff); // will print "foo"

        tryToNullifyBuff(buff); // this has no effect on the original reference 'buff'

        System.out.println(buff); // will still print "foo" because a copy of 
                                  // reference buff is passed to tryToNullifyBuff() 
                                  // which is made to reference null 
                                 // inside the method leaving the 'buff' reference intact
     }
}
```

This can be done with other mutable objects like Collection classes for example. And this is
not at all a bad practice, in fact certain designs actively use this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`str` has the value `"blablabla"` because a *reference* to the StringBuilder instance is passed to `toCommand()`.

There is only one StringBuffer instance created here - and you pass a reference to it to the `toCommand()` method. Therefore any methods invoked on the `StringBuffer` in the `toCommand()` method are invoked on the same instance of the `StringBuffer` in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always bad practise. Consider the task to assemble an email, then you could do something like:

```
 StringBuilder emailBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 createHeader(emailBuilder);
 createBody(emailBuilder);
 createFooter(emailBuilder);
 sendEmail(emailBuilder.toString());
```

It surely could be used to create confusion and for public API one should add a note or two to the javadoc, if the value at the passed reference is changed.

Another prominent example from the Java API:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

And as other already explained and just to complete the answer: The value of the reference of the StringBuffer (<-- start using StringBuilder instead!) is passed to `toCommand` so outside and inside the `toCommand` method you access the same StringBuffer instance.

Comment: The code I noticed this in was actually in a project using threads, so there might actually be a reason for them using StringBuffer.

Comment: Could be - or maybe it was originally written for Java 1.4.2 or less as StringBuilder was introduced with Java 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Since you get a reference to the instance you can call all the methods on it, but you can't assign it to anything else.

```
public void toCommand(Stringbuffer buf) {
    buf.append("blablabla"); // okay
    buf = new Stringbuffer(); // no "effect" outside this method
}
```

Comment: And here is what I believe the reason why I thought objects couldnt be altered in a method. Creating a new StringBuffer in that method only changes which object "buf" (the copy of the reference to the original object) refers to. 

Thx all now I understand!!

Comment: @sebastianlarsson: Exactly, you got it

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object to a method, unlike in C++, only the reference to the object gets copied. So when a mutable object is passed to the method, you can change it and the change gets reflected in the calling method.
In case you're too much into C/C++ programming, you should know that in java, pass by reference(in C++ lingo) is the default(and the only) way of passing arguments to methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just in response to some of the comments about the SCJP (sorry don't have permissions to leave comments - apologies if leaving an answer is not the right way to do this).

In defence of the SCJP exam, passing object references as method parameters AND the differences between immutable String objects and StringBuffer / StringBuilder objects are part of the exam - see sections 3.1 and 7.3 here:

http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/scjp/scjp-exam-objectives.html

Both topics are covered quite extensively in the Kathy Sierra / Bert Bates study guide to the exam (which is the de facto official study guide to the exam).